# Win32, How to access button on toolbar

Tags: winapi

Let's say I have a compiled binary program that runs and exposes some GUI on the screen.
I need from another program in Win32 to access its toolbar, find a button and click on it.

I know how to find Hwnd of the toolbar, but I don't really know how to enumerate the buttons on it.
Any ideas how to do it in Win32 calls?

Is there any tool like Spy++ that is capable of showing button handles under toolbar?
Spy++ doesn't do it.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use automation API?

Comment: Automation API is a slower way of accessing objects.

Comment: I cannot see the part of your question where you specify performance constraints.

Comment: Hopefully you noticed the part of the question where I mention "How to do it in Win32"?

Comment: Yes. So what. Since when were the automation APIs not part of Win32? I'm not sure why you want to reject the simple and effective way to solve your problem.

Comment: The problem is already solved using automation API and it works fine. The point of question is how to do the same with Win32 without third party technologies

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "third party technologies". The automation APIs are part of Windows. Anyway, to do it your way, you first need to learn how a windows toolbar works. Start with the documentation on MSDN.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33710/discussion-between-alek-gaisman-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a standard Win32 Toolbar control, then you send the toolbar a [`TB_BUTTONCOUNT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787297.aspx) message to determine how many buttons are on the toolbar, then send a [`TB_GETBUTTON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787319.aspx) message to retrieve information about a button at a given index.

The tricky part is that the [`TBBUTTON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760476.aspx) structure that receives the button info needs to be allocated in the same process that owns the toolbar, so you will have to:

1. call [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to retrieve the toolbar's process ID
2. call [`OpenProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320.aspx) to get a `HANDLE` to that process
3. call [`VirtualAllocEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890.aspx) to allocate the structure inside of that process
4. send the [`TB_GETBUTTON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787319.aspx) message(s) to the toolbar, specifying the pointer returned by [`VirtualAllocEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366890.aspx)
5. call [`ReadProcessMemory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553.aspx) to copy the structure data back into your own process so you can process it as needed
6. call [`VirtualFreeEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366894.aspx) to free the allocated memory.

Comment: This approach (although "correct") suffers from a *whole* host of issues. Don't do this. Use the right interface for the job: automation. And, @AlekGaisman, although I know that's not always possible, reconsider your design. If I agree that I'll pay for lunch tomorrow, doesn't mean that I *also* agree to let you reach into my pocket, pull out my wallet and take my AmEx.

Comment: Many mentions of "use automation instead" on this question, but no actual examples or links.  Any pointers to the "better" way of doing this?  I'm facing the exact same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR you can get the `HWND` of a toolbar button by calling [`GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481%28VS.85%29.aspx). The first parameter is the `HWND` of the toolbar, the second parameter is the ID of the button (the one you set in its `TBBUTTON` structure). You need to have the button ID to use this approach.

=== EDIT ===

In addition to EnumChildWindows, suggested by @graham.reeds, you can try [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Move the target window to the foreground, calculate the screen coordinates of the upper-left corner of the toolbar (using its HWND), add the X-Y offset of the middle of the target button, and send a mouse click to that position. (I used this approach successfully to click on Flash and Silverlight objects rendered inside the IE window.)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have button ID, I am using MS Spy++. It shows only a ToolbarWindow32 object but doesn't show buttons on it.Is there any tool that drills down into toolbar structures

Comment: @AlexG In theory you could actually brute force the nIDDlgItem integers out of the application. This is an option I am considering at least...

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked it sends a WM_COMMAND message to the main window. Simulating a click on a toolbar button is not very practical. A better approach is to use Spy++ to find the WM_COMMAND message and its parameters. Then in your program send this same WM_COMMAND message.

Comment: i understand the concept of WM_COMMANDS, but i still need to access the button as the button holds the only status indicator of running process.

Answer (score -1):

Off the top of my head:

Use [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633494%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the child controls of the toolbar.

Then use [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633520%28VS.85%29.aspx) to see if it is a button.

If it is [PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to it to invoke it's operation.

Comment: The individual buttons on most toolbars are not child controls with their own HWNDs.  They're usually just regions painted directly on the toolbar.

Comment: Now it makes much more sense, Thanks you