# How do I get the position of Windows Toolbars in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I've been tasked from my workplace to create a program which, when ran, moves the cursor to over a Windows Toolbar within the Taskbar, and left-clicks it.

The rationale for this is that everyone’s using the same mapped Toolbars on their desktop and considering how tiny the button is to activate the dropdown, and how often we’re clicking on it, it becomes tedious.

I’ve made code to move the mouse cursor to a hardcoded location on the taskbar and send the left-click message, and it works pretty fantastically actually.

The reason why the above approach won’t work however is because everyone’s Toolbars are constantly changing locations (variable number mapped apps on taskbar, docking/undocking laptop from large monitors).

The only thing that’s constant is the name of the mapped Toolbars. What I really need is to determine the screen coordinates for Toolbar “x”, and then move the mouse cursor to that.

I have honestly researched this for some weeks now, looking into UI Automation (people C# one of this is deprecated but not C++), and several other related posts, but with no success. I’ve found a C++ solution, but it didn’t actually include a code example (says “do this, then do that”); plus I’m not as- proficient in C++.

Through Spy++ I’m able to see the coordinates, window handle, etc. for these Toolbars, which leads me to believe this must be possible. FindWindow won’t work because the window handle isn’t constant.

Any help you can provide on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you post the details about the C++ solution that you found, it may be possible to convert it to C#.

Comment: Well, use UI Automation then. I don't know why you believe it were deprecated.

Comment: @IInspectable [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768046/system-windows-automation-is-extremely-slow/41768047#41768047) is the post that states System.Windows.Automation is deprecated (in the answer).
The answer suggests they use certain .h files instead, which means it's not deprecated for C++ right (I'm big noob obv)?

Comment: I finally found [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724168/win32-how-to-access-button-on-toolbar?rq=1).
The answer for the post contains a solution that's honestly just over my head right now. If you're able to help me turn that into something in C# that'd be incredible.

Comment: Try to see if [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) can generate P/Invoke signatures for the COM interfaces then.

Comment: System.Windows.Automation (.NET) is deprecated in the sense it's not maintained by Microsoft. But this is just a wrapper over the underlying UI Automation (native) technology that is *not* deprecated. Just add a COM reference to UIAutomationClient from a C# project. The code will be slightly different but very similar to existing System.Windows.Automation C# code.

Comment: @SimonMourier What's your opinion of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768046/system-windows-automation-is-extremely-slow?noredirect=1&lq=1) post? They state that .NET's System.Windows.Automation is extremely slow, but that the native one is really fast (I think).
If it was a simply wrapper don't you think it'd have similar speed?

Comment: Absolutely. Nevertheless, you should use the UIAutomationClient COM object and forget about System.Windows.Automation.